Extending Linux partition and adding swap in a dual-boot system
I initially gave my Linux partition 30GB, 27GB to root and 3GB to swap system.
the problem is that my swap is on the end of the disk and is not adjacent to D.
(So that I can extend D, shrink it, extend linux, shrink D again, create swap (though I guess what I plan to do is stupid))
what I want to do is to extend Linux partition up to 50GB and give it like 5GB swap. preferably to have swap on the end of the disk.
PC Partitions, 5th partition on Disk0 is linux

Your question is not clear, but a few observations - (a) Changing partitions can risk data loss - so backup before you do anything.   (b) Consider changing swap from a partition to a file - this is easier to manage and has become fairly standard - especially for SSD, which I'm guessing this is based on the size.  (c) Have you looked into gparted for "moving" your partitions about?

Also, just FYI, you can have multiple swap partitions/files - so you can always have a 3gb and 2gb swap partition seperate, and simply have the OS use both of them.   Of-course, I am skeptical of having large swap partitions as if that amount of swap is used it will nail performance.


What version of Ubuntu? Newer versions don't need a swap patitition, but can use a swap file.
If this is a relatively new installation, it is far easier to reinstall than to try moving an existing installation to the left, which is time consuming and risky. To reinstall, but with more room:


Remove the last two, 27.1 & 3.8 GB partitions, making that uallocated free space.
Resize (shrink) the 270 GB NTFS partition to perhaps 250 GB or so.
Make the ~20 GB on the right of that partition free space, contiguous with the ~31 GB from before.
Install Ubuntu. For any version from 20.04 onward, don't make a swap partition. The installer should find and point to that ~51 GB unallocated space; let it use all.

